# Java Methods and return statement

Tags: java

I am trying to test a class i'm working on. I want to run a print statement that takes a monthly salary for an employee multiply it by 12 to give me the annual salary then adds 10%. I have gotten everything to work except for the last part

Here is my code so far (This is just partial code)

constructors

```
 public double findSal(){
    return this.monthlySalary * 12;
}

public double giveRaise(){
    return this.monthlySalary * 12 * 0.10;
}

System.out.printf("The yearly salary for " +employee1.getfirstName()+" " + employee1.getlastName()+" " + "With a 10% raise is: $" +employee1.giveRaise()+ "\n");
System.out.printf("The yearly salary for " +employee2.getfirstName()+" " + employee2.getlastName()+" " + "With a 10% raise is: $" +employee2.giveRaise()+ "\n");
```

This is the error I am getting when I run

Exception in thread "main" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = 'r'
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.conversion(Formatter.java:2691)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.(Formatter.java:2720)
    at java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2560)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2501)
    at java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:970)
    at java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:871)
    at labex4oop.employeeTest.main(employeeTest.java:35)
Java Result: 1

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Neither of the methods shown are _constructors_, they're just normal methods.

Comment: Question is why is the last argument the employee1.giveRaise() giving me an error and not working

Comment: Question title is not matching with your question.

Comment: Why are you using `printf()` when you don't plan to use format specifiers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code suffers from a minor oversight:

```
Public double giveRaise(){
    return this.monthlySalary * 12.0 * 1.10; // was 0.10
}
```

You also need to convert from `double` When printing the values and you have to escape the percent sign in your literals (since you use `printf` where `%` has placeholder semantics):

```
System.out.printf("The yearly salary for " +employee2.getfirstName()+" " + employee2.getlastName()+" " + "With a 10%% raise is: $" +String.valueOf(employee2.giveRaise())+ "\n");
```

Comment: Still gives me an error after changing it to 1.10. I get this error Exception in thread "main" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = 'r'
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.conversion(Formatter.java:2691)
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.<init>(Formatter.java:2720)
 at java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2560)
 at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2501)
 at java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:970)
 at java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:871)
 at labex4oop.employeeTest.main(employeeTest.java:37)
Java Result: 1

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.printf("With [...] a 10% raise [...]");
                                  ^ // your problem is here
```

`printf()` is for formatted output. Placeholders in the format string are introduced via `%`. `10% raise` in your code is interpreted as a `%r` formatting specifier. Since you neither have any arguments to format nor is `%r` a valid `printf` format specifier, you get the error message telling you that your format string is wrong.

To include a literal `%` you must use `%%`. Or stop using `printf()` at all because you are not using its capabilities:

```
System.out.println("The yearly salary for " 
   + employee2.getfirstName()
   + " " + employee2.getlastName()
   + " with a 10% raise is: $" 
   + employee2.giveRaise() + "\n"
);
```

Comment: Thank you it is now working, silly mistake on my part.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the correct answer.
I have tried it.`public double giveRaise(){
    return this.monthlySalary * 12 * 1.10;
}`